# Use JavaScript RegEx to match Byte Order Mark (BOM)

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Is there an easy way to use JavaScript regular expressions to match a BOM? I'd like to build a utility that does this in Node.js, but the following doesn't seem to match anything:

```
fixBomFiles : function(offendingFiles) {
    var i = 0,
        file, js;

    for (i=0; i < offendingFiles.length; i++) {
        file = offendingFiles[i];
        js = this.parent.fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');

        js = js.replace(/\uFEFF/g, '');

        this.parent.fs.writeFileSync(file, js, 'utf8');
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I'm guessing my regular expression is bad, or I shouldn't be using UTF-8 encoding for read/write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derp... the RegEx was fine. My script was not correctly loading "offendingFiles".